# MQTT Retained messages not received when subscribing same topic from different applications at the same time

Tags: java, mqtt, paho, hivemq, emq

**TL;DR**

When subscribing to the same topic tree with multiple clients *at the same time*, not all clients receive the retained messages as expected!

**in detail / use case**

In a real project several applications subscribe (nearly at the same time because they are started in parallel) to the same MQTT topic (with wildcard). The topic contains about 500 retained messages (each in an own sub topic level) which all applications are expected to receive (they are subscribing with QoS 1).

Beside the "configuration" messages also data topics are subscribed with the same MQTT connection. No persisted state is required (and wanted here). Therefore the application instances connect with `cleanSession=true`.

For my understanding it would be sufficient if the application instances would each connect with a fixed clientId as *cleanSession=true* should avoid any state handling. But to be really sure that no state is considered  a `unique MQTT clientId` is generated for each connect.

**observerd behavior**

Unfortunately not all application instances get the retained messages.. Some get no messages at all from the topic - regardless of how long the subscription lasts. I first thought that the maxInflight (client side) or max_queued_messages (server side) configuration might be the reasons, but after increasing both to 500,000 I guess this is not the reasons behind the failure.

**reproduction as test**

Therefore I created [this](https://github.com/FrVaBe/MQTT/tree/master/mqtt-client-showcase) github project with a repro. There is a unit test class in the repro `MqttSubscriptionTest` with the test method `multiThreadSubscriptionTest`. When executing this test some (1000) retained messages will be published first in the `@BeforeClass` method. After that, 10 instances of a `MqttSubscriber` class which implements the `IMqttMessageListener` and `Runnable` interface will be instantiated and executed. Each MqttSubscriber instance will be executed in an own thread with an own MqttClient instance and will subscribe to the topic tree with the retained messages. This is logged to the console as follows:

```
----------- perform subscriptions
Subscriber-3 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-0 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-2 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-4 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-5 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-6 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-1 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-7 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-8 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
Subscriber-9 subscribing topic 'mqtt/client/showcase/mutliThreadSubscription/#'
```

The test will wait some time and after that validate the subscriptions. It is expected that each Subscriber received the 1000 retained messages:

```
----------- validate subscriptions
Subscriber-4: receivedMessages=1000; duration=372ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-0: receivedMessages=1000; duration=265ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-5: receivedMessages=1000; duration=475ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-7: receivedMessages=0; duration=0ms; succeeded=false
Subscriber-6: receivedMessages=1000; duration=473ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-8: receivedMessages=0; duration=0ms; succeeded=false
Subscriber-9: receivedMessages=1000; duration=346ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-3: receivedMessages=1000; duration=243ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-1: receivedMessages=1000; duration=470ms; succeeded=true
Subscriber-2: receivedMessages=1000; duration=357ms; succeeded=true
```

Most subscriber received the expected 1000 messages in a very short time (some hundreds ms). But some (here Subscriber-7/8) did not receive a single message (duration is 0 because they never finished). The situation is not better when giving the subscribers more time to receive the messages. They just won't get them.

I have no idea why this happens. No error messages are shown on the MQTT broker or client side. If you can give any help this would be super useful for me, because I dependent on the reliable delivery of retained messages.

**Repro on GitHub**: [FrVaBe/MQTT/mqtt-client-showcase/](https://github.com/FrVaBe/MQTT/tree/master/mqtt-client-showcase)

- I tested with a local EMQ and HiveMQ broker. If you want to run the test you need to run a broker on your machine at localhost:1883 or change the configuration in the test class.
- I use the Eclipse Paho Java Client MQTT
- I subscribe with `cleanSession=true` because I do not want to have any state (the connection is used to subscribe to several topics and the delivery of missed messages is not wanted)

Comment: You've tagged this with 2 different brokers (emq and hivemq) but not actually said which one you are using

Comment: @hardillb Right. Sorry. I tried both brokers and the problem occurs on both. Maybe it's a problem (?) of the Eclipse paho java MQTT client. Or a configuration issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HiveMQ people were kind enough to take a look at this problem. They suspect the cause in the Paho client and the use of the `IMqttMessageListener` in the subscribe. There is a described issue [#432](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/432) of the presumed Race Condition.

Lesson learned: Better use `MqttCallback` instead of `IMqttMessageListener`

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `cleanSession(true)` during connect, see explanation here: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-retained-messages-example/

I used mosquito for tests and it's internal message queue is only 100 by default.

HiveMQ has max-queued-messages.

Emq config has something similar http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/config.html#mqtt-message-queue.

I fixed the example code in the repo. Works for me.

Edit: Just tested it with Emq (`docker run --rm -ti --name emq -p 18083:18083 -p 1883:1883 quodt/emq-docker:latest`) and it works fine.

Basically, it's cleanSession: Must be false.
Apart from that, the waiting states in your test codes are bad. They are too short on my machine. Use a latch or other real sync mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tested using `cleanSession(false)` but that does not work (reliable) for me. I even can't connect this way because I also subscribe to topics where I do not want to retrieve any state. Receiving retained messages with cleanSession=true should work imho. The wait state might be short but I do not expect high performance broker to need longer. Nevertheless I also tested with 60 seconds which made no difference. Some subscriptions just do not receive any messages :-(

Comment: Yes, you should still receive all retained messages regardless of  cleanSession state

Comment: The cause for the behaviour seems to be a race condition in the Paho client (see my answer).